# PGAdmin 4 window shows no content

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pgadmin

This is my first attempt at running a local PostGres. I have installed PostgresSQL 16.
I am doing a Spring Boot tutorial and wish to connect through Spring Data JPA to a PostGres database.
This includes PGAdmin 4. This is the only executable the start menu offers under
When I open pgadmin I just get a window with a NW.JS logo in it, no details of servers to connect to, no UI. It's not as if it doesn't start - the window opens there's no stack trace.
Can someone tell me what I'm missing? Maybe I need a running PostGres instance but I can't identify how to do that. As I say the PGAdmin excutable is the only one offered.
Any help is appreciated.
[PGAdmin window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et8kk.jpg)

As mentioned I'm doing a Spring Boot tutorial and trying to connect to a PostGres table.
I had attempted this with docker images of Postgres and PGAdmin. These were accessible as UI at localhost. But repeatedly tried to connect via the app resulted in password authentication errors. I tried all variations of PGAdmin and and registered user passwords.
Instead I've stopped the docker images and attempted to set up a local installation, now finding the above problem.
Really not sure as to how to troublehshoot this and there's little advice I can dig up online.